# Use recursion to reverse a list in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, ml

I am trying to use recursion to reverse a list (without mutating it) with a helper function, **without** matching or folding. 
Goal:

```
# let list1 = ["a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"];;
val list1 : string list = ["a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"]
# listreverse list1;;
- : string list1 = ["e"; "d"; "c"; "b"; "a"]
```

My code:

```
let rec helper remainder reversed =  
if remainder  = [] then reversed else List.hd remainder :: (helper (List.tl remainder) reversed);;

let listreverse lst = helper lst [];;
```

However, currently this will just return the same list without reversing it. Seems like adding the head to the back of the list is my issue. Is there any minor fix I can do to make this reverse the list?

Answer (score 3):

You're always passing the empty list as `reversed`, and adding the first element of the input to the *front* of the recursive result.

Let's work through a small test case – reversing `[1;2]`.

This is `helper [1;2] []`, and

```
   helper [1;2] []
—> if [1;2]  = [] then [] else List.hd [1;2] :: (helper (List.tl [1;2]) [])
-> List.hd [1;2] :: (helper (List.tl [1;2]) [])
—> 1 :: (helper [2] [])
—> 1 :: (if [2]  = [] then [] else List.hd [2] :: (helper (List.tl [2]) []))
—> 1 :: (List.hd [2] :: (helper (List.tl [2]) []))
—> 1 :: 2 :: (helper [] [])
—> 1 :: 2 :: if []  = [] then [] else List.hd [] :: (helper (List.tl []) [])
—> 1 :: 2 :: []
—> [1;2]
```

Consider a deck of cards.
Take the top card and put it down on the table.
Then take the second card and put it on top of the first card.
If you keep doing this until the first deck is empty, you will have a "new" deck that's in the reverse order from the first.

The point of the helper function is exactly this principle – you can reverse the elements by "moving" them from `remainder` to `reversed`, and the recursive call should be a "tail call" – that is, it just returns the result without doing anything with it.

```
let rec helper remainder reversed =  
    if remainder = [] 
    then reversed 
    else helper (List.tl remainder) (List.hd remainder :: reversed)
```

then

```
   helper [1;2] []
—> if [1;2] = [] then []    else helper [2] [1]
—> if [2]   = [] then [1]   else helper []  [2;1]
—> if []    ≈ [] then [2;1] else helper []  ...
—> [2;1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the question to think about is, Why does your helper function have two parameters?

It appears that your plan is to use one paramter to build up the result, while the other parameter represents the unprocessed part from the end of the original list.

If this is the plan, then you should be returning the result at the end (when the original list is empty). But your code returns an empty list.

A second observation is that if you are building up the result as a parameter to your helper function, then you don't need to add anything to the result that comes back from the helper.

Comment: I updated it and changed empty list part. But it does not seem to do anything. Could you explain more about the second observation? Did I add anything to the result?

Comment: Well, you're adding the head of the remaining list to the result of calling the helper function recursively. If your plan is as I said, all the necessary work is done by specifying the two parameters properly, and the returned value will be the reversed list (with no  modification necessary).

Comment: How do I specify something in a recursion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You have a recursive call to `helper`. It specifies values as parameters (`List.tl remainder` and `reversed`). I'm just saying to take a look at these values. They don't seem to fit with the plan of having two parameters with the names you've used.